# Using a single custom validation rule in different models

Tags: php, validation, model, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to write my first project in CakePHP2 (I used CakePHP1 before) and I have the following problem.

I have several models that require a custom validation rule for a field (personal numeric code). The validation rule is quite large so I don't want to repeat the code in each model.

Instead, I thought about writing a component with a function that will receive a string as a parameter and validate it, and just calling that particular function from each model.

I read that components should be used in controllers, so maybe this is not the best way to do it?

What I'm trying to do is actually extend ModelValidator and add my own custom rules, but I have no idea if that is possible.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question: Behaviors.

The CakePHP structure recomends that:

- Components should be used in Controllers
- Helpers should be used in Views
- Behaviors should be used in Models

To define the behavior I did the following:

1. In the app/Model/Behavior/ValidateBehavior.php file:

   ```
   class ValidateBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

       // the first param is the model object
       public function isValidCnp($Model, $data) {

       // data is an array that contains the field name and value
       // define validations rules here
       // return true or false
       }
   }
   ```
2. In my model app/Model/User.php where I need to validate the data:

   ```
    class User extends AppModel {

       // link the behavior to the model
       public $actsAs = array('Validate');

       // define a custom validation rule that calls a function from the behavior
       public $validate = array(
          'cnp' => array(
              'custom' => array(
                 'rule' => array('isValidCnp')
              )
           ),
       );
    }
   ```

The good thing about Behaviors is that they seem to act like parent classes and they can also contain callback functions for beforeSave, beforeDelete, etc.

The model can call a function from the Behavior like a method of his own, which means behaviors can also be used in controllers:

```
$this->User->isValidCnp()
```

Answer (score 0):

No, components are not for models.  What I do for my custom validation rules is add methods to the AppModel.  Then you can use them in any validation array for your models.

See the Cake book section about making custom validation methods, if you don't already know how to use them:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

But instead of putting the method in each model you need it in, put it in your AppModel instead (if you don't have an AppModel class, create one like below and save it to `app/Model/AppModel.php`.  All of your models will inherit this class, so your custom validation methods will be available to any model.)

Here is a simple example:

```
/**
 * app/Model/AppModel.php
 */
class AppModel extends Model {

    /**
     * Validation rule for integers
     *
     * @param  mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateInteger($value) {
        return preg_match('/^\d+$/', array_shift($value));
    }

}

/**
 * app/Model/MyModel.php
 */
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'my_field' => array(
            'rule' => 'validateInteger',
            'message' => 'This field only accepts integers'
        )
    );

}
```

I have also toyed with the idea of having a custom validation behavior, which contains all these validation methods, but I found it doesn't work particularly well and isn't as convenient, due to limitations of a Behavior.

Comment: It's a good answer, but unfortunately it doesn't quite apply to what I'm looking for. The project I'm working on is very large, so by adding different methods in there, the AppModel will become difficult to maintain, plus those methods are not needed in every model. I do know how to create custom validator methods and I use them in most cases, but the validations rules I'm trying to integrate are larger and I don't want to repeat the same code over and over again. I'm thinking that maybe an interface can be useful (a model extends AppModel and implements an interface with validations rules).

Comment: Nope, interfaces are a bad idea since they only define the methods names and params. :(

Comment: Then maybe you should look at adding your validation methods to a Behavior instead, which you can include in your models as and when you need them.  I found that method wasn't ideal though.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. It might not be ideal, but right now I don't see any other way.